# How to set fractional values for `seg_duration` when using ffmpeg's dash muxer?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm trying to set a fractional value for `seg_duration` when using ffmepg's dash muxer like the [docs suggest](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#dash-2). When I switch between integer decimal values, I don't get different results. How can I set a fractional value for `seg_duration`?

- E.g. Running my command with `seg_duration` equal to `1` produces the same [minBufferTime](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/9cc88ed4b71cdb2ea95e584a9cc3651d1cb52427/libavformat/dashenc.c#L1004-L1005) as using `0.01`.
- In the [source](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/9cc88ed4b71cdb2ea95e584a9cc3651d1cb52427/libavformat/dashenc.c#L119), `seg_duration` is represented as an `int64_t` so I don't see how you can pass a fraction to it.

Here's an example ffmpeg command to reproduce:

```sh
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose \
-i $INGESTION_PATH \
-seg_duration 0.01 \
-use_template 1 \
-use_timeline 0 \
-f dash $OUTPUT_PATH
```

Here's the snippet from the docs on `seg_duration`:

> seg_duration duration
>
> Set the segment length in seconds (fractional value can be set). The value is treated as average segment duration when use_template is enabled and use_timeline is disabled and as minimum segment duration for all the other use cases.

Comment: The user inputted value is treated as fractional decimal seconds, and stored as microseconds in the int64_t.

Comment: @Gyan can you show me the line that does that? If that's true, (( I expect it is )), why would `minBufferTime` not change? Its calculated by `seg_duration` * 2.

Comment: That is handled by the option parser, not specific to DASH muxer. How frequent are your keyframes?

Comment: oh so I should look there instead @Gyan? My keyframes and my GOP are set to 60. So you're saying a decimal value of 0.5 for `seg_duration` should work fine? Something like: `-seg_duration 0.5`

Comment: The DASH muxer will break on KF so your seg duration should be equal or longer than KF interval.